# Pointwise bounded sequence is "uniformly bounded"?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Consider the real valued functions of $x$, $F:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $F_n:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and suppose I have shown that 
$$
|F_n(x)-F(x)|\leq A \text{ } \text{ }\forall x
$$ 
Dos this mean that $\sup_{x} |F_n(x)-F(x)| \leq A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course. If $l := \sup_{x}|F_{n}(x) - F(x)| > A$, then by definition (if you are using this definition; otherwise we can prove this) there is some $x$ such that
$$
l \geq |F_{n}(x) - F(x)| > l - \frac{l-A}{2} > A,
$$
a contradiction.

Comment: Can you explain the second inequality in the row?

Comment: @STF Let $A \subset \Bbb{R}$ be bounded; let $l \in \Bbb{R}$. Then $l$ is called the supremum of $A$ iff for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is some $x \in A$ such that $l \geq x > l-\varepsilon$. Now you should try to do some exercise to patch all those up. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You have shown that $A$ is an upper bound for the set $\{|F_n(x)-F(x)|~:~ x \in \mathbb{R}\}$. Since $\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |F_n(x)-F(x)|$ is the *least* upper bound of the set $\{F_n(x)-F(x)|~:~x\in\mathbb{R}\}$, it is no larger than $A$.

Answer (score 1):

yes, since $A$ is an upper bound of $|F_n(x)−F(x)|$ its supremum, which is defined as the least upper bound will be

$\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |F_n(x)−F(x)| \le A$